# Issue with inserting widgets to a QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qgridlayout

I tried to create a widget having the following layout:

[image]

I tried several approaches, in my first one, I used a QVBoxLayout to that I added different Widgets that used the QGridLayout (so I would get the horizontal resize in the way I want it).

```
//pseudo code, just to show what I tried... 
myHeaderWidget::myHeaderWidget() {
    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout;

    layout->addWidget(new QCheckBox(), 0, 0, 1, -1, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignTop);
    setLayout(layout);
}


oneOfMyOtherWidgets::oneOfMyOtherWidgets() {
    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout;

    layout->addWidget(new QCheckBox(), 0, 0, 1, 1, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton(), 0, 1, 1, -1, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

    setLayout(layout);
}


mydialog::mydialog() {
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    setLayout(layout);

    layout->addWidget(new myHeaderWidget, 0, Qt::AlignRight);
    //here was the third widget containing Descr1 and Description2, as
    //drawn in image above
    layout->addWidget(new oneOfMyOtherWidgets, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);
}
```

The second approach was to use a QGridWidget as layout for **mydialog**, and my third approach was to add all those items to the same QGridWidget of **mydialog**.

All those results in the same, for me strange, behavior:
At any time I created those dialog and called show(), one of the following could happen:

1. all items were drawn in the way I wanted.
2. the checkboxes on the left were shown, but the buttons on the right were covering the description of the checkbox
3. the checkboxes on the left were correct, but I couldn´t found the buttons.
4. the buttons took all the space and you couldn´t see any checkboxes at all.

May somebody give me a hint, what I did wrong, or show me a way to create the layout I drew in the image?

Comment: Thanks for showing your example, I didnt know you could align during addWidget :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it by myself:

```
setColumnStretch(0,1);
```

was missing. The added widgets took the whole space in the cell, but the cell never grew.